# pdf generation not working in framework Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf-generation

I have a script that generates a PDF in Zend. I copied the script from converting image to pdf to another directory on the server. I now get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Cannot create image resource. 
File not found.' in /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php:38 
 Stack trace: 
 #0 /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('data/0116b4/cro...') 
 #1 /kalendarz/cms.php(56): Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('data/0116b4/cro...') 
 #2 {main} thrown in /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php on line 38
```

Code of website, example link to image (http://tinyurl.com/8srbfza):

```
else if($_GET['action']=='generate') {
    //1 punkt typograficzny postscriptowy (cyfrowy) = 1/72 cala = 0,3528 mm
    function mm_to_pt($size_mm) {
      return $size_mm/0.3528;
    }

    require_once("Zend/Pdf.php");

    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 

    $page_w = mm_to_pt(100);
    $page_h = mm_to_pt(90);

    $page = $pdf->newPage($page_w.':'.$page_h.':'); 
    $pdf->pages[] = $page; 

    $imagePath= 'data/'.$_GET['id'].'/crop_'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg'; //to nie jest miniaturka
    $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath);


    $left = mm_to_pt(0);
    $right = mm_to_pt(100);
    $top = mm_to_pt(90);
    $bottom = mm_to_pt(0);

    $page->drawImage($image, $left, $bottom, $right, $top);     

    $pdfData = $pdf->render(); 

    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$_GET['id'].".pdf"); 
    header("Content-type: application/x-pdf"); 
    echo $pdfData; 
    die();
  }
```

Comment: Just add the code which generated the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath expects a valid file and uses is_file function call to check the file existence.

First of all, use absolute path to the image, instead of using the relative one. You can specify the absolute path by referring to your APPLICATION_PATH. For example,

```
  APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/data
```

If APPLICATION_PATH is not already defined in your code, paste this code in your public/index.php

```
 defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Then, check if 'data/'.$*GET['id'].'/crop*'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg' exists. Also, check if the file has proper permissions to be accessed by PHP.

Note : Use the [Zend request object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html) instead of the $_GET.

Comment: What is your absolute path to data folder?

Comment: Try giving /kalendarz/data/0116b4/crop_0116b4.jpg as the argument to imageWithPath

Comment: Also, check if the file has read permissions for the apache user

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Cannot create image resource. File not found.' in /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('/kalendarz/data...') #1 /kalendarz/cms.php(42): Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('/kalendarz/data...') #2 {main} thrown in /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php on line 38`

Comment: Isn't /kalendarz/ a root folder?

Comment: You might want to test a simple file operation like an fopen with the specific directory to see if the script can access the path correctly.

Comment: It was a large and a small letter. Already did it,. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path:

```
$imagePath = '/kalendarz/data/'.$_GET['id'].'/crop_'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg';
```

or:

```
$imagePath = APPLICATION_PATH.'/../data/'.$_GET['id'].'/crop_'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg';
```

you might also want to put some validation on `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: `$imagePath = '/kalendarz/'.$_GET['id'].'/crop_'.$_GET['id'].'.jpg';`
the same error


`Notice: Use of undefined constant APPLICATION_PATH - assumed 'APPLICATION_PATH' in /kalendarz/cms.php on line 42
APPLICATION_PATH/data/0116b4/crop_0116b4.jpg
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Cannot create image resource. File not found.' in /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /kalendarz/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('APPLICATION_PAT...') #1 /kalendarz/cms.php(44): .....`
second way

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? You said you've moved servers so perhaps it's different on the new one.

Comment: Is the error still 'File not found'? If so, are you 100% sure that the path you are using is correct?

Comment: Yes, still error "file not found". Path is from phpinfo(). I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: It's the path *to the image file* that is not correct, your phpinfo screenshot doesn't help as it doesn't show what this is. Find out where the image file is on the file system and compare that to the path you're supplying to `imageWithPath()`

Comment: I have access only to the catalog `kalendarz`. How can I see the all path?